# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: .net, clone

"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" exception is thrown at .Clone() operation in .net.

I'm using framework 2.0.

Any ideas what the reason could be.

Thanks in advance.

ravi

Comment: What are you trying to clone?

Comment: It may be helpful if you at least mentioned the type of the object being cloned, and even better, told us what had happened to it up to that point.  The error itself is extremely generic, as there are plenty of reasons why objects can't be cloned at times.

Answer (score 1):

Your question unfortunately doesn't contain enough information to be given a straight answer.

However, you could definitely try to analyze the Clone method of the object throwing exceptions at you using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Comment: Code fails at the following statement.
installmentPeriod = (DatePeriod)period.Clone();

where period is inherited from ICloneable interface.

This is hapening while I'm debugging the code.

Can Reflector be used while debugging

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the answer for the question. Issue was there is an exception thrown in one of the methods during cloning. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The number of form fields that are sent in a single post on your page is 1000, i.e The default value of MaxHttpCollectionKeys is 1000, try to set a larger value.

The solution is Add Key into webconfig **add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001"**